# Is there an Android equivalent to iOS's "CallKit"?

Tags: calls, hardware, voip

This actually seems like a very Android-like feature. When I heard about it, I thought there might be an Android equivalent.

It lets VoIP apps use the standard phone app to call/receive calls, integrating with the phone's contacts and recent calls list. Basically, it turns VoIP calls into regular phone calls (at least for apps that support it).

If there is nothing like this on Android, is there any indication that Google will add something like this to a future version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Android does, but it's not very well documented. The [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html) class was introduced in Marshmallow and allows an app to register itself as a voice service, the user needs to manually enable the voice service through the phone settings (same place you would enable/disable SIP accounts).

Once this is done you can choose between registered voice services when placing a call using the native dialer, or set one as the default. Incoming calls to your voice service should also trigger the native dialer.

Side note, but also interesting, Marshmallow also introduced the ability to register your app as the default dialer too.

Comment: Very interesting. I'm not aware of any apps using this, which I find strange.

Comment: @JonnyWright the reason not even Hangouts app uses this API is because it is completely useless. It is ridden with bugs. I highly discourage anyone thinking of using this API, you are in for a dead-end.

Comment: @rcorrie, could you post an answer with your recommended alternative?  Thanks

Comment: IOS Call kit supports sip or web RTC calling . does connectionService also support those formats